# Have data locally - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to learn Flutter on my own and trying to build a chat app which is connected to the OpenAI api. It works fine, I can send messages and receive answers as well, but every time I close the app all of the messages are gone. I will add Firebase to the project later. Is there any solution to save the chat history to the device/app so I can have it locally and it will be there next time I open the app?

Comment: There are many possible solutions. Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75742236/flutter-local-database-storage/75742375#75742375

Comment: While not strictly related to your question, connecting to OpenAI APIs directly from a mobile app would expose your API key, which is not something you would want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) pub.dev package in order to achieve that. For exaple, if you wish to persist `String` data, you could do something similar to the below:

```
  /// Initializes the shared preferences object to be used in this class.
  Future<SharedPreferences?> initializePreferences() async {
    preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return preferences;
  }

  /// Used to persist String data.
  Future<void> persist(String key, String data) async {
    await preferences?.setString(key, data);
  }

  /// Retrieves persist data of type String.
  String? getString(String key) {
    String? data = preferences?.getString(key);
    return data;
  }
```

You can persist & retrieve various types of data (objects, lists, list of objects etc) by serializing / deserializing them as JSON objects. A full example of a sample data persist service can be found at [black-out/data_persist_service/](https://github.com/gbrandtio/black-out/tree/main/client/lib/services/data_persist_service).

Hope it helps.
Cheers,